# Networking between two VMs on different host adapters having different subnet in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hostadapter

I want to make a network between two VMs on different host adapters having different subnet in VirtualBox. The base OS is ubuntu, I did a source based ping using this command but ping is not successful:

```
ping -I vboxnet0 192.168.57.1
```

Where vboxnet0 is 192.168.56.0/24 and vboxnet1 is 192.168.57.0/24. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using VyOS as a virtual router. It's free and once VyOS is installed as a virtual machine, you can create routes between the subnets your VMs are on. Lots of documentation for VyOS out there. See: http://vyos.net/wiki/Main_Page.